# Pseudoinversion on multivariate problem and differential equation between parameter variational rates at order higher than one

Tags: taylor-expansion, pseudoinverse

I've been trying to fit some data with polynomials using a pseudo-inversion library (numpy.linalg). There are two real functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f=-\alpha g$, $\alpha > 0$, and

$$
f=f(t_1,\ldots,t_5),
$$
$$
g = g(t_1,\ldots,t_5),
$$

where $t_1,\ldots,t_5$ are real parameters. The parameter $\alpha$ has been estimated by an **experiment**, so I have two sets of experimental values for $f$ and $g$, $\{f_1,\ldots,f_{12}\}$, $\{g_1,\ldots,g_{12}\}$.

What I want to do is, given a good model, to reproduce this experimental result ($\alpha$) numerically.

Starting from rather a good prior estimation of the parameters, I generate five set of numbers for each parameter:

- for the first one, $\{(t_1)_1, (t_1)_2,\ldots, (t_1)_{12}\}$;
- for the second one, $\{(t_2)_1, (t_2)_2,\ldots, (t_2)_{12}\}$;
- etc...

so that $(t_i)_{j+k} - (t_i)_{j} \equiv (t_a)_{b+k} - (t_a)_{b}$ $\forall i,j,a,b,k$, that is varying them by the same differential every time.

Next, I write the problem to first order like this

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
f_1\\
f_2\\
\vdots\\
f_{12}
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1& (t_1)_1 & (t_2)_1 & \dots & (t_5)_1 \\
1& (t_1)_2 & (t_2)_2 & \dots & (t_5)_2 \\
\vdots\\
1& (t_1)_{12} & (t_2)_{12} & \dots & (t_5)_{12} \\
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
c_0\\
c_1\\
\vdots\\
c_5
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

or

$$
\vec{f} = T \cdot\vec{c}.
$$

I then *pseudo-invert* $T$ and apply the result to $f$ and get a good estimation for $\vec{c} = [c_0,c_1,\ldots]$, that I will call $\vec{c}_f$.

I repeat for $g$ and get $\vec{c}_g$.

Of course $\vec c_g\neq \vec c_f$, however

$$
\frac{\vec c_f}{c_{f1}} \simeq \frac{\vec c_g}{c_{g1}},
$$

which represents

$$
\frac{f}{\partial f/\partial t_1} \simeq \frac{c_{f0}}{\partial f/\partial t_1} + t_1 + \frac{\partial t_1}{\partial t_2} t_2 + \dots
$$

or

$$
\frac{f}{c_{f1}} \simeq \frac{c_{f0}}{c_{f1}} + t_1 + \frac{c_{f2}}{c_{f1}} t_2 + \dots
$$

with this I know that, to first order,

$$
dt_2 \simeq dt_1 \times \frac{c_{f1}}{c_{f2}}
$$

so I can finally run my model where, for each unit of variation $dt_1$ of the first parameter, the $n^{th}$ one varies this much:

$$
dt_n \simeq dt_1 \times \frac{c_{f1}}{c_{fn}},
$$

and the result is nice, **but I can do better**.

- Question number one: **how to I set up this calculation (pseudoinversion) to higher order?** I presume that having higher order coefficients is sufficient, but please confirm, I'm insecure.
- Question number two: It's not easy to build this matrix (higher order), so **are there python libraries that you are aware of that build such matrix automatically given a dataset?** If not, I should generate every possible combination of mixed derivatives I think, **right?**
- Question number three (the most important): Let's say I do construct the correct matrix (not easy) and find the best fit coefficients,**what do I do with them?**

To second order, for instance, I have something like (please remember that all of this is finite)

$$
\frac{f}{\partial f/\partial t_1} \simeq \frac{c_{f0}}{\partial f/\partial t_1} + t_1 + \frac{\partial t_1}{\partial t_2} t_2 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial t_1}{\partial f}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t_2\partial t_2} t_2^2 + 
 \dots
$$

where

$$
\frac{\partial t_1}{\partial f}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial t_2\partial t_2} = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t_2} \frac{\partial t_1}{\partial t_2} - 
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t_2}
\frac{\partial }{\partial f}\frac{\partial t_1}{\partial t_2}
$$

and similar equations can be written for mixed derivatives terms.

How do I use these coefficients to determine how $t_n$ varies with respect to $t_1$, that is writing an equation similar to this:

$$
dt_n \simeq dt_1 \times \frac{c_{f1}}{c_{fn}},
$$

but for higher orders?

Thank you for reading and thank you very much in advance for your help

**Edit**: *My shy and inconclusive attempt at second order corrections*

If I define

$$
c_{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_p} = \frac{\Delta(\Delta\dots(\Delta f)\dots)}{\Delta t_{\alpha_1}\dots \Delta t_{\alpha_p}}
$$

I get

$$
\Delta t_\beta = \frac{c_\alpha}{c_\beta} \Delta t_\alpha
$$

for first order and

$$
\Delta t_\beta = \frac{c_{\gamma\delta}}{c_{\alpha\beta}} 
\frac{\Delta t_\gamma \Delta t_\delta}{\Delta t_\alpha}
$$

for second order terms.

This implies

$$
\Delta t_\gamma \Delta t_\delta = 
\frac{c_\beta c_{\alpha\beta}}{c_\alpha c_{\gamma\delta}}
$$

which one may consider a second order term, but **is it?**

Please correct me if I'm wrong with what follows: to *solve* the first order problem I had to fix a *normalization* term and I chose $\alpha = 1$ by dividing the Taylor expansion by

$$
\partial f/\partial t_1.
$$

Now that I'm dealing with higher order, I'm apparently required to fix **two** normalization terms instead, so by choosing

$$
\alpha = \beta = 1,
$$

I get, for $\delta = \gamma$,

$$
(\Delta t_\gamma)^2 = \frac{c_{11}}{c_{\gamma\gamma}}
$$

that **confuses me**, since it's in no way related to, for instance, $\Delta t_1$ or any other finite differential.

Is it ok? Should I expect that the correct way to modulate any of this parameters could be, to second order, **independent** of what I do with any other?

Is it even right to call this a *second order correction*? How would I even modulate $t_\gamma$ given these two (first and second order) contributions? Just by adding them together with a $1/2!$ factor in front of the latter?

All of this sounds wrong to me but I have no idea how to tackle this.

*How?*

Thank you again